# Drop-down selection form, in rails 4

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm trying to create a dropdown form which allows the selection of one name, listed from a table of names.

In the controller I simply have:

```
def selection
   @data = Location.all
end
```

I'm struggling greatly with rendering this @data within a dropdown selection form. Everything I've tried yields the error: "undefined method `to_key' for #Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f07d83b2a90>"

I understand I should probably be using "f.collection_select", perhaps something like:

```
<%= form_for @data do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :name, Location.all, :url, :name %>
<% end %>
```

---

Sorry if this question is a little dumb, I'm really new to programming. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out what I needed:

To populate the form with data I used:

```
@formlist = Location.all.pluck(:name)
```

The code for the form I needed:

```
<%= form_for :select, :url => results_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:name, options_for_select(@formlist))%>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

the results_path had to be post instead of get:

```
post 'results' => '<mycontroller>#results'
```

the chosen name could then be picked up using:

```
def results
   @choice = (params[:select])[:name]
end
```

Being able to pick up a @choice variable now allows me to return some analysis based on user input.

---

I'm sure there are better ways to do this but I'm happy with what I came up with.

The post here "http://www.austinstory.com/rails-select-tag-and-options-for-select-explained/" was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:url` try to use `:id` as the primary key.

Maybe this link will help you:
http://www.redguava.com.au/2010/12/rails-basics-adding-a-drop-down-list-to-your-forms/